# Getting data from editText multiple times

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am making an app in which the user writes in the editText and click on button so that the data written comes as a textview.
Now when another user comes and write in the same editText ,the data should come in another textview and so on.

how to get data from same edit text in multiple textviews?

Comment: You get a String from the EditText. Afterwards it your wish which TextView you want to apply it to. So what's the problem?

Comment: What have you written so far? It would help understand the details of your question (i.e. do you have working code for transferring text for one `TextView` but not more? Are the `TextView`s pre-defined in xml, or are you creating them programmatically? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For this you must know already typed text. You can store them into and array list

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and when user touch the button you can check that input with list.

```
if (list.contains(input)) {
    // do sth
} else {
    // do ther stuff
}
```

and here is the your solution while adding text view:

if we assume your layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

if (list.contains(input)) {

    View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);

    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText(input);
    valueTV.setId(5);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);


} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

Note: instead of add them to view you can add them into a list view. and it will be better 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/